# One page checkout page is completely blank. No log errors anywhere

Tags: onepage-checkout

Our Magento version is 1.9. We use a custom theme, but even though Magento can fallback to the Mage core onepage checkout controller, it shows a blank page. Also, there is none logs whatsoever in any of the logs. Nothing in Magento's var/log/exception.log, and var/log/system.log and nothing in PHP's php_error_log. I have traced the cause into the onepage Controller, - the indexAction, and the flow never goes out of `$this->loadLayout();` What can cause this?

Comment: Do you use a custom module for your checkout?

Comment: Yes and a typo in a module was the cause. I actually had to set the error_reporting(-1) at the beginning of the indexAction() method in order to see the error. The php.ini has error_reporting set to E_ALL already. Why is Magento changing this setting beats the hell out of me, and I don't like this. I was not able to see this error unless manually added this line immediately before the culprit line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typo in one of the custom modules was the cause. I actually had to set the error_reporting(-1) at the beginning of the indexAction() method in order to see the error. The php.ini has error_reporting set to E_ALL already. Why is Magento changing this setting beats the hell out of me, and I don't like this. I was not able to see this error unless manually added this line immediately before the culprit line.